# How to see the elements from an array of pointers to stucts in VS Code during debugging?

Tags: arrays, pointers, visual-studio-code, watch

The code is like:

```
struct A{
int n;
...
};
A* a[1000];
```

Now I need to see values of all `n`.

Two ways I can think of are not good.

- Typing `a[0]->n`, `a[1]->n` is too slow.
- Typing `*a@1000` will list many other members of struct `A`, finding `n` from them is hard.

Is there a way to solve this better?

Comment: you can write a function that show this data and call that function from the debug console: `dump_n(a)`